# Selenium - python webdriver exits from browser after loading

Tags: python, selenium, automation, crash, webdriver

I try to open browser using Selenium in Python and after the browser opens, it exits from it, I tried several ways to write my code but every possible way works this way.
Thank you in advance for help

```
`from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
s=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get("https://amazon.com")`
```

I expected the browser to open amazon.com and stay like this until I close or the programme close it.
Actual result - when the browser loads the website, it exists from itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use driver.close() function after getting result ;)

Comment: Thank Ilya, but it doesn't work either :/